# What is $\frac{\partial \overline{z}}{\partial z}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

We can write $$x=\frac{z+\overline{z}}{2}$$ where $z$ is a complex number. Here $z=x+iy$.

What is $\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}$? My book says that it is $\frac{1}{2}$. But is $\frac{\partial \overline{z}}{\partial z}=0$?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, $\frac{\partial\overline{z}}{\partial z} = 0$. You can compute that from the definitions,

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\overline{z}}{\partial z} &= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} - i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)(x-iy)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial x} + (-i)^2\frac{\partial y}{\partial y} - i\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(1+(-1)\cdot 1 - i(0+0)\right)\\
&= 0.
\end{align}$$

Then you can obtain $\frac{\partial x}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2}$ for example from $x = \frac{1}{2}(z + \overline{z})$. Or from $\frac{\partial x}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)$ using the definition of the Wirtinger derivatives.

Comment: This means $\bar z$ is a constant with respect to $z$?